# WebSocket app runs on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, websocket, java-ee-7, tomcat9

I have [this small web app](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/544f570eb35f1160224d0b8090f39bd6). My symptoms are: when I run the web app locally, the connection to the local Tomcat WebSocket facilities is well established. However, if I deploy it on Heroku, open connection to the WebSocket, it goes straight to `readyState` 3.

**Edit**

Upon an attempt to connect to Heroku, `heroku logs --tail` gives:

```
2021-09-26T10:14:20.686213+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/download" host=rodioning-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=257ec5e3-2ecb-486d-b05e-b905cb624f1f fwd="86.115.191.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=1215 protocol=https
2021-09-26T10:14:59.319236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/download" host=rodioning-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=009f5d8c-935a-4acc-ae0b-0665bb54616b fwd="86.115.191.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1215 protocol=http
```

Comment: In your JavaScript you use `/download` as URI path for your websocket. It should be rather `/<context-path>/download` if you want it to work regardless of how the application is deployed. You can retrieve it with the EL expression `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` if you rename `index.html` to `index.jsp`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Is there any chance  to solve the issue without converting to a .jsp file?

Comment: You can compute the context path in JavaScript, e.g. `location.pathname.substring(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Tried `location.pathname.substring(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))`. The same issue persisted.

Comment: @coderodde Can you paste the logs using `heroku logs --tail` when you try to connect to the websocket?